# Clarification on Jech's Proof of Fodor's Lemma

Tags: set-theory

My question concerns Jech's Proof (Set Theory, 3rd Edition) of Fodor's Lemma (that given a regressive function $f$ on a stationary subset $S$ of $\kappa$, there is a stationary subset $T$ of $S$ with the property that $f$ is constant on $T$):

> Let us assume that for each $\gamma < \kappa$ the set $\{\alpha \in S: f(\alpha) = \gamma\}$ is nonstationary, and choose a club set $C_\gamma$ such that $f(\alpha) \neq \gamma$ for each $\alpha \in S \cap C_\gamma$. Let $C = \Delta_{\gamma < \kappa} C_\gamma$. The set $S \cap C$ is stationary and if $\alpha \in S \cap C$, we have $f(\alpha) \neq \gamma$ for every $\gamma < \alpha$; in other words, $f(\alpha) \geq \alpha$, which contradicts the fact that $f$ is regressive.

My question is, why does following statement hold:

> The set $S \cap C$ is stationary.

(Clearly(?) this is not needed in the proof, since all we require for a contradiction is that $S \cap C \neq \emptyset$, which holds because $S$ is stationary and $C$ is a club set (Lemma 8.4. in Jech).)

Comment: This is because the intersection of a stationary set and a club is stationary.

Comment: More precisely, suppose $S$ is stationary and $C$ is a club. Let $C'$ be any club. Then $C \cap C'$ is a club. Since $S$ is stationary, $S \cap (C \cap C')$ is nonempty. Hence $(S \cap C) \cap C'$ is nonempty. Since $C'$ is an arbitrary club, it follows that $S \cap C$ is stationary.

Comment: Oh I see, because if $S \cap C$ is nonstationary and hence does not intersect $C'$, then $S \cap C \cap C' = \emptyset$, but $C \cap C'$ is a club, so this contradicts. Edit: Thanks for the elaboration. Funny we used the same notation. If you want to add this comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: There is a quasi-converse, although not as important: If $S$ is a non-stationary subset of $k$ then there exists a regressive $f:S\to k$ such that every fiber $f^{-1}\{x\}$ is $bounded$ in $k.$ Proof: Let $C$ be club in $k$ and disjoint from $S$. For $c\in S$ let $f(x)=\cup (x\cap C).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the intersection of a stationary set and a club is stationary.

Suppose $S$ is stationary and $C$ is a club. Let $C′$ be any club. Then $C\cap C′$ is a club. Since $S$ is stationary, $S\cap(C\cap C′)$ is nonempty. Hence $(S\cap C)\cap C′$ is nonempty. Since $C′$ is an arbitrary club, it follows that $S\cap C$ is stationary.